# Why Installation of Perl Module Statistics::Multtest fails for me?

Tags: perl

I am trying to install a perl module Statistics::Multtest in my system. But Installation keeps failing every time. What might be the reason
I am suing this command to install

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Statistics::Multtest'
```

But I am getting this error Message

[image: Error Message Screen Shot]

I am unaware of the real problem
Even I upgraded the essentials and perl too
But still the problem persists
What might be the reason?

Comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=112782

Comment: Sorry didn't understand much. "Please do not allow pod means'?

Comment: @ThulasiR did show you that it's a known problem and there is a request to the author/maintainer of this module to fix it. It is a problem with the test that checks if the POD documentation is correct... which fails. These tests are fine for authors and maintainers, to ensure a certain level of 'kwalitee' and have nothing to do with the code itself. – since other tests are passing fine, a 'force install' is a save way to go

Comment: Yeah thank u for your clear explanation. I tried force installation and I got the same error.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. CPAN installation output is plain text. Why would you think posting it as an image is at all helpful?

Comment: Yeah it's a plain text when I was posting the text it was saying it contains code. I edited several times and posted but i was unable to post the error messages. Finally I thought this would be helpful. So, I posted as image

Comment: *I thought this would be helpful.* Well, you were wrong. We can't cut and paste text from an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is [a known problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=112782) with this distribution. But given that the distribution hasn't been updated for five years and the author hasn't responded to the bug report in eighteen months, I'd suggest that the chances of getting it fixed are slim.

It's only a documentation error, so it's safe to ignore and force the installation, but it's probably a good idea to email the author (his email address is in the documentation) and ask him if he's aware of the problem.

**Update:** I found a Github repository for the module, so I've sent [a pull request](https://github.com/jokergoo/Statistics-Multtest/pull/1) to fix the problem.

**Update 2:** The [fixed version](https://metacpan.org/release/Statistics-Multtest) is now available on CPAN.

Comment: thank you..You helped me.. finally I installed the module